# Please update sonar-maven-plugin to at least version 2.3

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I'm building a project in Jenkins with Sonar Integration.

Everything goes smoothly until the sonar analysis part. I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.2:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project project-whatever: Can not execute SonarQube analysis:
>   Please update sonar-maven-plugin to at least version 2.3 -> [Help 1]

and then the build fails.

I must explain that I have no references to sonar in my project pom.xml. This has been done exclusively with Jenkins configuration.

I'm using the latest available versions both on Jenkins (1.599) and Sonar (5.0). All Jenkins plugins are updated.
Already looked for a way to update the sonar-maven-plugin version, but I can´t find it: either it doesn't exist or I'm not looking at the right places...

Does anyone have any ideia how to work around this?

Comment: The plugin is deployed on Maven central repository (see http://search.maven.org/#browse|1409554664), so you either have forced a specific version of the plugin (in your POM or a parent POM) or you have some kind of a repository manager (like Nexus) that prevents you from downloading latest versions.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thanks for the fast response.
As I've mentioned before, I have no reference to the plugin in any of my POMs. I do have a Nexus server, but it hasn't been the source of any problems so far. I'll look into it!

Comment: I checked my Nexus server, the proxy ir working fine, I can see the 2.5 version of the plugin there. However, if I check my Jenkins installation (/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin) I only have the 2.2 version.

Comment: Well, I have the feeling that there's a problem with your Jenkins / Maven installation, because you shouldn't have such an issue - this is really transparent when your Maven install has full access to Maven central repository.

Comment: Couldn't it be that the Sonar Plugin (for jenkins, not maven) has a obsolete dependency?

Comment: The Jenkins plugin has no locked dependency on sonar-maven-plugin. One difference between version 2.2 and 2.3 is that Maven prerequisite was updated from 3.0 to 3.0.2. Can you provide your Maven version? Also you may try to force all plugin update using Maven -U option.

Comment: I don't know if the following i possible: could try to delete the Maven Version 2.2 from you Repository and update the files again, so Nexus is forced to download the latest version?

Comment: I 'was' going to do that, and when I checked de maven repository I noticed a new 2.5 folder. I figured that somehow the problem had solved itself and went to run a build with sonar - it failed with the same error. Then I effectively deleted the 2.2. folder, keeping only the 2.5. Ran the build again and it failed once more with the same error. I checked the repository and the 2.2 was there again. So... something is actually requiring the 2.2. version explicitly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by going into Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Scroll to the SonarQube section -> Click advanced -> fill in "Version of sonar-maven-plugin" with the verison you would like to use.....I used 2.5.

Comment: It worked! Is this a new option on the sonarqube plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the root `pom.xml`, then following should work as well:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

More info in [SonarQube docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven)