# Why do I can't manage to use the sonar-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I encounter the following error when I run `mvn sonar:sonar` in my project directory:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:5.1:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project policytest: Please update sonar-maven-plugin
>   to at least version 2.3

The setting in my `pom.xml` points to the right version:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>  
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>5.1</version>  
</plugin>
```

I could not find where to fix it. Help is very appreciated.

Comment: I was able to eliminate the error message and run the sonar code analysis  with maven. What I mainly did is:  
delete the local repository (~/.m2/repository).

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40656951/5151575)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin` (note the groupId).

See [Which sonar-maven-plugin version to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980521/which-sonar-maven-plugin-version-to-use) for more details.